# Need help passing data between two activities

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. Mainactivity.java and door1.java. On mainactivity.java I have a textview named plaintxt that I need to pass to textveiw named door1textview on door1.java. I have been trying for a while but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

use below code in Mainactivity whether you need to pass data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), door1.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

and you will be able to receive data in door1 activity like below

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("KEY");
```

you can see more from [here](https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

use intent to pass data between two activity 
 like this
**MainActivity**

```
String value=user_name.getText().toString().trim();
```

***on Button Click***

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
theIntent.putExtra("name", value);
startActivity(theIntent);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 Intent i= getIntent();
i.getStringExtra("name");
```

another way to get data

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String userName;

if (extras != null) {
userName = extras.getString("name");
// and get whatever type user account id is
 }
```

Comment: can not get it to work